# Missing times in r, how to subset by timeframe?

Tags: r, subset, fill

I have two summer's worth of hourly precip and discharge data collected from Durango data stations from 2012-2013. For this research, I am analyzing how each precip event impacts river discharge on an hourly basis. The discharge data has data every 15 minutes, every hour, every day no matter what the weather. The precip data only has times for hours that had rain. Here are two graphs I made of the first few precip events I have:

```
#after loading in my .CSVs 'animas' and 'durango':
disc1 <- animas[c(8700:9000), c(3,5)]
prec1 <- durango[c(3:11),c(6:7)]

ggplot(data = disc1, aes(x=datetime, discharge))+geom_point()+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
ggplot(data = prec1, aes(x=DATE, HPCP))+ geom_point()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[discharge, all hours get plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnNYL.jpg)
[Precipitation, missing hours as zeros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtUAw.jpg)

The way that precipitation is plotting with missing hours is unacceptable for my objective. I need to somehow generate these missing hours and fill the empty precipitation("HPCP") values with zeros, so I can plot it on the same time scale as discharge.

Also, is there a way to separate this data into individual precipitation events, excluding events that total less than 0.05 inches? (As opposed to setting all the time bounds for hundreds of precipitation events by hand). I need to generate sets of hours that a precipitation event occurred and add the discharge values for those hours. Will be plotting these eventually, as well as taking the difference in time between peak rainfall an peak discharge. What data structure should I use, and how?

This seems difficult because zeros between precipitation hours not present in all cases; for example, two rain events from different dates could be in adjacent rows, one after the other. How can I sort it fast? Can a tail be added to include points from 6 hours before and after the start/end time?

I have messed around with the .csv to obtain two possible date/time configurations (HPCP in this file is precip). Which is better for convenience and plotting with ggplots?

[image: data1]
[image: data2]

All the hours with 0's in HPCP are measurement hours with the flag of 'F', which means a trace amount of precipitation was detected. These are too insignificant for my analysis.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a way to summarise your question and add `dput(data)` and expected output?

Comment: A combination of `seq.Date` and `merge` might help you.